# Product Of Series With Increment Powers

Tags: power-series, products

I found this interesting aptitude question and I don't know how to solve this genre of question. Any help is welcome :)

$$\prod_{n=1}^{49}n^n=1¹\cdot 2²\cdot\ldots\cdot49^{49}=?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Taking a logarithm converts this to a summation rather than a product, which may be more approachable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Semiclassical, let  $$X=\prod_{n=1}^{49}n^n=1^1\cdot 2^2\cdot\ldots\cdot49^{49}$$ so $$\log(X)=\sum_{n=1}^{49} n\log(n)$$ which is much easier to handle with a pocket calculator. Being patient for a couple of minutes, you should get that $\log(X)=4167.802939$, from which $$X \approx 1.131926083941\times 10^{1810}$$ while the approximate value of the original product is $1.131925630\times 10^{1810}$.

May be, you could be interested by the fact that $$\prod_{n=1}^{m}n^n=H(m)$$ where $H$ is the hyperfactorial function.

**Added later**

In a comment, Semiclassical spoke about a type of Stirling expansion. According to
Mathworlds page, it write $$H(m)=A e^{-\frac{m^2}{4}} m^{\frac{m^2}{2}+\frac{m}{2}+\frac{1}{12}} \left(1+\frac{1}{720
  m^2}-\frac{1433 }{7257600 m^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^5\right)\right)$$ where $A$ is Glaisher number $(\approx 1.282427129)$. Using the first term only, for $m=49$, we then obtain $1.131924975477377\times 10^{1810}$. Notice that the second term is only $\frac{1}{1728720}$ compared to $1$.

Comment: Mathworlds' page on the hyperfactorial includes a Stirling-style asymptotic series which likely gives a decent approximation.

Comment: Based on that computation, calling that "a decent approximation" was more than a bit of an understatement for the $m=49$ case (in regards to the relative error, that is).

Comment: @Semiclassical. I totally agree with you and I thank you ! It is really amazing ! Cheers :-)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this expression has shown up a few times as previous MSE questions, so the interested reader can certainly find more info